# Get XML item by ID when use xmlhttp-request

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm starting to work with XML and XMLHTTP-Request and I didn't understand how to get a item by ID. For example:

In my XML document I got that:

```
<note id="501">
    <to>Exemplo 2</to>
</note>
<note id="502">
    <to>Exemplo 2</to>
</note>
```

In my HTML I got that:

```
document.getElementById("to").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("to")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

With that code, I just get the first one (501), but how to define by ID and get the second one (502)?

PS.: I got the examples from here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will become crazy by traversing an XML by raw javascript. Get jQuery and then:

```
var $xml = $( $.parseXML(xmlDoc) );
var a = $xml.find('note[id=501]').text();
var b = $xml.find('note[id=502]').text();
```